# What is the best way to perform multiple text search in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

What is the best way to perform multiple text search in SQL. Is there a better approach in below case?

> Select * from Employee where Observation like 'test%' and (Observation like '%Left%' or Observation like '%(L)%' or Observation like  '%(Lft)%')

```
Name        Observation  
Tessa       Left Eye test       
Jo          (L) Eye test
Lisa        Leg test
John        Right Eye test
Baby        Left foot test 
Nan         test left arm
Linda       Eye test (Lft)
```

> Select * from Employee where Observation like 'test%' and (Observation like '%Left%' or Observation like '%(L)%' or Observation like  '%(Lft)%')

Comment: I belive `SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
WHERE CONTAINS(Observation, '"test*" AND ("Left" OR "(L)" OR "(Lft)")');` should be a better way. Match single words and phrases with precise or fuzzy (less precise) matching. more in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15